# How does recursive of number sum work in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I have this code for investigating of groupSum by using a recursive method. 
I do not understand how the recursive works in this example. I used debug but still do not understand it.

```
   public class test {

    public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {

        if(target == 0) 
            return true;
        if (start == nums.length)
             return false;
        if (groupSum( start+1, nums,  target-nums[start])) // what is the meaning of this line ? can we change this line to make the code easier to understand ?
            return true;
        return groupSum( start+1, nums,  target);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 0;
        int y [] = {2,4,8};
        int k = 10;

        test t = new test();
        boolean result = t.groupSum(x,y,k);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without saying what you find confusing, its hard to know what you don't understand.  Using the debugger should be able to help and the more you use more it will be useful. (It comes with practice)

Comment: There's a good treatment of this problem at http://codingbat.com/prob/p145416. You use the same test case. Did you come here from there? What about their explanation did you not understand?

Comment: yes I came from there .. I did not understand this line properly `groupSum( start+1, nums,  target-nums[start])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two recursive calls

```
groupSum( start+1, nums,  target-nums[start])
```

try to see if we can reach the remaining target if we subtract the value at `nums[start]`

or can we reach the target without this number.

```
groupSum( start+1, nums,  target);
```

It the debugger doesn't help you can add debugging statements

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;
    int[] y = {2, 4, 8};
    int k = 10;

    boolean result = groupSum(x, y, k);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    System.out.println("groupSum(" + start + ", " + Arrays.toString(nums) + ", " + target + ")");
    if (target == 0)
        return true;
    if (start == nums.length)
        return false;
    if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start]))
        return true;
    System.out.print("or ");
    return groupSum(start + 1, nums, target);
}
```

prints

```
groupSum(0, [2, 4, 8], 10)
groupSum(1, [2, 4, 8], 8)
groupSum(2, [2, 4, 8], 4)
groupSum(3, [2, 4, 8], -4)
or groupSum(3, [2, 4, 8], 4)
or groupSum(2, [2, 4, 8], 8)
groupSum(3, [2, 4, 8], 0)
true
```

You can see it tried all all the values which left `-4` then it went back and tried not including `8`, and then it tried not including `4` which turned out to be successful.

Comment: thank you ... can we write this `groupSum( start+1, nums,  target-nums[start])` in another way ?

Comment: @DfgfHgh you could change the signature to make it a little clearer. if the debugger doesn't help you I suggest printing the inputs on each call at the start.

Comment: @DfgfHgh I have updated my answer to include debug logging.